# Android: padding in nested layouts

Tags: android

Especially for padding and margin, it would be cool to be able to inherit from parent views.

I donT know if you would agree but, it becomes a mess as soon as I take a control out of a layout and put it in another container.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:padding="20dp">
    <!--       ^^^^^^^^^^^ -->         
   <RelativeLayout           
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:padding="20dp">  ---?
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content""/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleDate2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RelativeLayout/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```

When I decide to put the text view in a second layout as in this example, the paddings get messed up because, now they are applied twice around the borders.

[image]

Is there way to keep the parent padding in a way that it trickles down to the inner layouts gracefully?

I hope it s clear.

Comment: create dimens.xml resource file and store all of your numeric sizes within it. and use them through out application

Comment: What about using a custom style?

Comment: :S from the comments, i assume it s not understood. i ve just edited, trying to make it clear

Comment: have you tried with relativelayouts and use align left / right to ?

Comment: yes. The problem is not with aligning but being able to consistently padding inner controls. in this example, the 'textView' is padded twice on top and left.